# select one of 2 columns in a view according to if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a footbal matches table where we have 2 columns : Team 1 and Team 2
In another table I have the teams Table:
So,

```
 If teams.name = Team1.name => Team2.name is Away Game
If teams.name = Team2.name => Team2.name is Home Game.
```

I made this view that work properly from a course online and I cant edit it:

```
CREATE 
VIEW `additional_time_goals` AS
    SELECT 
        `p`.`team` AS `Team`,
        `p`.`player_name` AS `Player`,
        `p`.`Round` AS `Round`,
        `p`.`time` AS `time`,
        `p`.`extra_time` AS `Extra Time`,
        `m`.`Team 1` AS `Team 1`,
        `m`.`Team 2` AS `Team 2`
    FROM
        (`players_scored` `p`
        JOIN `matches` `m` ON ((((`p`.`team` = `m`.`Team 1`)
            OR (`p`.`team` = `m`.`Team 2`))
            AND (`p`.`Round` = `m`.`Round`)
            AND (`p`.`extra_time` IS NOT NULL))))
```

So instead of selecting the two columns Team 1 and Team 2, I want to see if p.team = team 1 so I will display Team 2 and vice versa.

Comment: What do you want to do. Please clarify in detail....

Comment: @OP: Add sample data to your post and expected output from them as well.

Comment: `if table1.name = table1.name` ???

Comment: how can table1.name = table1.name be false? unless it's null of course

Comment: wait guys I will edit my post and please remove your downvote :@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `CASE WHEN` you are looking for. I'd further recommend to get rid of all those parantheses that make your criteria so hard to read. And consider using simple column names (e.g. team1 instead of "Team 1" where you always need to quote because of the space character).

```
create view additional_time_goals as
  select 
    p.team,
    p.player_name as player,
    p.round,
    p.time,
    p.extra_time as "extra time",
    p.team as team_a,
    case when p.team = m."Team 1" then m."Team 2" else m."Team 1" end as team_b
  from players_scored p
  join matches m on p.team in (m."Team 1", m."Team 2")
                 and p.round = m.round
                 and p.extra_time is not null;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but i think this might help you

```
CREATE 
VIEW `additional_time_goals` AS
    SELECT 
        `p`.`team` AS `Team`,
        `p`.`player_name` AS `Player`,
        `p`.`Round` AS `Round`,
        `p`.`time` AS `time`,
        `p`.`extra_time` AS `Extra Time`,
        `m`.`Team 1` AS `Team 1`,
        `m`.`Team 2` AS `Team 2`,
    CASE WHEN p.team = team 1 THEN team 2
         WHEN p.team = team 2 THEN team 1
         ELSE '' as val
    FROM
        (`players_scored` `p`
        JOIN `matches` `m` ON ((((`p`.`team` = `m`.`Team 1`)
            OR (`p`.`team` = `m`.`Team 2`))
            AND (`p`.`Round` = `m`.`Round`)
            AND (`p`.`extra_time` IS NOT NULL))))
```